# Preserve contents within angular braces as it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to do some HTML processing. I have some issues while using angular braces.

This is my code:

```
content = "Testing angular braces with some <random content>"
parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(content)
p parsed_html.inner_html
```

The output is

```
"Testing angular braces with some <random content></random>"
```

Obviously I am not expecting those `</random>` closing tags to occur.

How can I skip those content within angular braces. The content might contain HTML elements too.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is text with embedded `<` and `>`, but those don't surround actual HTML tags, then you need to encode them for HTML. Nokogiri assumes those are real tags and will do fixups to close the tag and generate relatively correct markup.

```
require 'htmlentities'
require 'nokogiri'

html_encoder = HTMLEntities.new

content = html_encoder.encode("Testing angular braces with some <random content>")
# => "Testing angular braces with some &lt;random content&gt;"
parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(content)
puts parsed_html.to_html

# >> Testing angular braces with some &lt;random content&gt;
```

If you have both HTML tags and pseudo-tags, then your task becomes much more difficult as you'll have to preprocess the HTML tags and change them to some other delimiter, run the encoding, then re-process the text to return the HTML tag delimiters back to what they should be, then parse it with Nokogiri.

How to do that is left as an exercise for the reader as it's an entirely different question.